# Is it maintain invariant when mathematical structure is changed over view of tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis, vector-analysis, data-structure

In short, tensor is a invariant something and

In Computer Engineering, for the convenience of calculation we modify a vector to multi-dimension array like $$[1,2,3,4] \rightarrow [\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{matrix} ]$$

But dose we said that the above change keep invariant? or just isomorphic mapping?

Because I understand invariant of tensor only applies when it's the same mathematical structure. like bellow
$$[1,2,3,4] \rightarrow [2,4,5,6]$$

Comment: Invariant under *what*?

Comment: In my knowledge, invariant under coordinates

Comment: This is difficult to answer as stated, because it seems there are unstated assumptions about what "is" a vector or matrix versus a tensor, and possibly incompatible uses of language between mathematics and computer engineering. It might help to phrase the question in concrete, specific terms rather than abstracting. It's also possible the question is not a good fit for Math.SE because a complete answer would be an introduction to linear invariants....